# Android problem getting Arraylist<double[]> from cursor

Tags: android, cursor, arraylist

I need to get a value from my cursor.  The value needs to be in this format:

```
        List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
```

The problem is when I do the ".add" it errors wanting me to change it to "length".  I have to have it in the List for the app to work at all.  Here is my code, is there a way to do that?  What am I doing wrong?

```
    cursor = managedQuery(Provider.CONTENT_URI,
            proj,
            null,
            null,
            null);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
        double value; 
        column_value = cursor.getColumnIndex(CsvProvider.VALUE);
        value = cursor.getDouble(column_value);
        values.add(value); //this did not work
        values.add(new double[] {value}); //this did work
    } ;
```

Thanks Mike!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should never paraphrase errors. If you get an error, copy and paste it into your question.

As to your problem:

You have a list of double arrays, i.e. every single entry in your cValues List needs to be a double[]. Instead, however, you're just adding a plain double. That won't work. I don't know how your list is supposed to be setup, if you put the [] in by mistake or if you really need a list of arrays, but assuming that every entry needs an array of one double, then you need to add a `new double[] { value }`.

Side note: Why not simply `while (cursor.moveToNext()) { ... }` instead of this do/while construct?

Comment: Thanks Mike. It wasnt really an error but more of the quick fix in Eclipse when the red squigly line is under the bad code. I will clean up the do/while and I agree that it would be better with the moveToNext. This is what works but I need to populate that from my cursor: List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>(); values.add(new double[] { 4.9, 5.3, 3.2, 4.5, 6.5, 4.7, 5.8, 4.3, 4, 2.3, -0.5, -2.9, 3.2, 5.5, 4.6, 9.4, 4.3, 1.2, 0, 0.4, 4.5, 3.4, 4.5, 4.3, 4 });

Comment: Okay, so you want ONE entry in the List with an array of doubles? Well, in that case, create a double array with `new double[cursor.getCount()]` and write into it in your loop.

Comment: This fixed it for me "...then you need to add a new double[] { value }".  Thanks!  I tried that once but other errors kept popping up.  I guess I just gave up too early because after fixing a few of the others that popped up all is well.